# Convert 2 binary search trees to red black trees

Tags: merge, tree, type-conversion, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

if I got two binary search trees ,named T1 and T2 with m and n nodes and h1 and h2 heights.

How I can convert those trees into one red black tree with time complexity Θ(max(m,n)) and space complexity Θ(max(h1,h2))?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the trees already balanced? If so then they are already RB except for coloring the nodes black (which can be done in T(max(m, n)) for a single tree, If the trees are not balanced it is going to take quite a bit more work.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir we don't have any more information about the trees so they can be not balanced as well.